# Sampling with joins using Django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a method in one of my models that right now fetches every link, and then does a random sample. Is it possible to make some form of join combined with a random selection using Django models? The current method seems like a great way to waste grind the application to a halt when the data grows. :)

```
class Link(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    in_list = models.ForeignKey( 'linkrotator.LinkList',
                                 related_name = 'links' )


class LinkList(models.Model):
    in_list = models.ForeignKey('linkrotator.LinkListList',
                            blank = True,
                            null = True,
                            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                            related_name = 'lists')

class LinkListList(models.Model):
    number_of_links = models.IntegerField()
    def get_links(self):
        links = []
        for list in self.lists.all():
            links.extend( list.links.all() )
        if len( links ) <= self.number_of_links:
            return links
        return random.sample( links, self.number_of_links )
```

Comment: Why do you need to iterate over all lists? Can't you just fetch all links that has a list associated? Something like `links = Link.objects.filter(list__isnull=False)`

Comment: @chromano - I'm grabbing links from a subset of lists. I updated the code with more of the Models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a bunch of random links like this:

```
links = self.lists.all().order_by('?')[self.number_of_links]
```

But... that doesn't filter on the lists you want. You might be able to do something like this to get that: `filter(list_set__id__in=...)`

Answer (score 1):

I thinks it's useful for [Getting a random row from a relational database](http://bolddream.com/2010/01/22/getting-a-random-row-from-a-relational-database/)